# Codeigniter's IgnitedDatatables Join error

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable

I am trying getting json from [Ignited-Datatables library](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables). I am trying to achieve following join in controller.

```
     $this->load->library('datatables');
        $this->datatables
        ->select('lab_orders.id, patient_id')
        ->from('lab_orders')
        ->join('patients', 'lab_orders.patient_id = patients.id')
        ->select('full_name');
      echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

I am getting the following error

> Error Number: 1060
>
> Duplicate column name 'id'
>
> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `lab_orders` INNER JOIN `patients` ON `lab_orders`.`patient_id` = `patients`.`id`) SqueryAux
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/lab/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

My Table structure is as follow

Patients

id | full_name | dob email | passcode

lab_orders

id | patient_id | dt_collected | dt_ordered

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this as well

```
$this->load->library('datatables');
$this->datatables
->select('lab_orders.id as lab_id, lab_orders.patient_id,patients.full_name,patients.id as pat_id')
->from('lab_orders')
->join('patients', 'lab_orders.patient_id = patients.id') 
 echo $this->datatables->generate();
```

Comment: there is no patients.patient_id. table fields are also up there.

Comment: the code is updated user lab_id and pat_id in code. id will not conflict now

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'pat_id' in 'on clause'

SELECT `lab_orders`.`id` as `lab_id`, `lab_orders`.`patient_id`, `patients`.`full_name`, `patients`.`id` as `pat_id` FROM `lab_orders` JOIN `patients` ON `lab_orders`.`patient_id` = `pat_id`

Comment: we are almost there. could you please check now ?

Comment: back to square one
Error : Duplicate column name 'id'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205518/discussion-between-amit-sharma-and-jay-wayne).